# PixelJunk Monsters - Best Stage for the "Construction Expert" Achievement?

Tags: pixeljunk-monsters

In Pixeljunk Monsters, you can get the Construction Expert steam achievement for building 10 towers in less than 30 seconds upon entering any stage.

But even if you buy the cheapest tower, the Arrow Tower, that means you'll need to start out with at least 1,000 gold pieces.  And you need to have the tower positions close enough.

What's the best map to try for this?

[image: Steam achievement]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **"easy 3" stage**, as seen in this Youtube video:

I remember following it to get that achievement. IIRC, you'll need some of those extra coins that drop from some random trees, but it's doable.